# Gatsby Error: Cannot find images job cache

Tags: gatsby

We pushed a deploy to Git to our master branch which just installed a sitemap Gatsby plugin which runs fine both locally, and on a test Gatsby environment however, when we ran this on live the builds started failing with the below. We then removed our code by reverting the commit and the builds are still consistently failing with the same error.

```
20:18:56 PM:
ERROR There was an unhandled error and we could not retrieve more information. Please run the command with the --verbose flag again.

20:18:56 PM:
20:18:56 PM:
  

20:18:56 PM:
  Error: Cannot find images job cache

20:18:56 PM:
  - prepare-build-changeset.ts:237 prepareBuildChangeSet

20:18:56 PM:
    [lib]/[@gatsby-cloud-pkg]/gatsby-inc-build-cli/lib/utils/prepare-build-chang    eset.ts:237:13

20:18:56 PM:
  

20:18:56 PM:
    [lib]/[@gatsby-cloud-pkg]/gatsby-inc-build-cli/lib/incremental-builds.js:140    7:30

20:18:56 PM:
  - incremental-builds.js:1407 Watching.handler
```